# PulseAudio not working when compiled from source: undefined symbol

Tags: pulseaudio

'm trying to set up my new RPI2 as a hub for my home automation projects. I've been trying to compile PulseAudio-raop2 to stream music to my AirPort Express. It compiles, but after running installing and running, it complains the following.

```
pulseaudio: symbol lookup error: pulseaudio: undefined symbol: pa_dbus_connection_unref
```

As for the installation, I just do the following:

```
sudo ./bootstrap
sudo make
sudo make install
```

I figure this is some kind of linking error though I have no idea how to solve this or even begin to search for the issue.

Here is the fork I am trying to install: https://github.com/hfujita/pulseaudio-raop2. I am running the suggested version of Raspbian from the official Raspberry site.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I think  you need to install portaudio devel package, Becuase your symbol start with `pa_*` and portaudio uses same format.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried again with libportaudio-dev and libportaudio0 installed but still have the same problem after recompiling and installing.

Comment: Then you have to recompile with portaudio , However i don't now soname of portaudio for `-l`